# How to set pulse animation on google marker at different zoom level?

Tags: android, google-maps, animation

I want **pulse animation** around `marker` and i followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41672994/pulse-ring-animation-around-a-google-maps-marker-in-android) but *the problem is when map zoom level change the pulse animation not showing proper*. Like when i set max zoom out **it shows like very small dot and not scaling according to zoom level of google map**

Comment: so you need to get the camera position (or projection) of your `GoogleMap`

Comment: yes i get projection value on different zoom level but how to determine that how much pulse radius i show on each zoom level so that animation is uniformly on each and every zoom level.

Comment: well you need to scale `animation.getAnimatedValue()` by a current zoom level in:  `lastUserCircle.setRadius((Float) animation.getAnimatedValue());`

Comment: yes exactly but how much value should i provide? Should i try manually determine all different value on different zoom level and set it so that pulse animation looks like uniformly?

Comment: see the docs: `Zoom level is defined such that at zoom level 0, the whole world is approximately 256dp wide (assuming that the camera is not tilted). Increasing the zoom level by 1 doubles the width of the world on the screen. Hence at zoom level N, the width of the world is approximately 256 * 2 ^ N dp, i.e., at zoom level 2, the whole world is approximately 1024dp wide.`

Comment: any luck ? did you found any solution ?